# Where is android SMS content provider?

Tags: android

I have an app which receives SMS on a specific port number and then I want to save them in android's default SMS app. But I cannot find the documentation for this content provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SMS provider was only documented as of KitKat (Android 4.4, API Level 19). The best writeup is [this Android Developers Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html), particularly for its discussions of what changed with API Level 19.

Prior to API Level 19, the SMS provider was undocumented and unsupported. I'm sure that there are plenty of blog posts and such that cover it, but only from the community, not from Google.

Comment: Just to inform you, as of API 19, you cannot write to sms content provider unless your app has been selected as the default sms app by the user :O